# How to solve Firefox 2.0 cross browser issues?

Tags: css, xhtml

How to Firefox 2.0 cross browser issues? When i make site using Firefox 3.6 then seee site in Firefox 2.0 some time it shows some layout problems.

for IE i can use conditional comments and different CSS but what to do for Firefox 2.0 issues

Comment: I'd note that Firefox 2 has a negligible market share and leave its users to fend from themselves. If you have to target a market where it still has significant marketshare (usually because people are depending on versions of Windows which no longer get security updates or support recent versions of Firefox) … then good luck.

Comment: Firefox really pushes its users to move to the latest version, and provides a really smooth upgrade path, with the result that Firefox 2 is hardly used anymore. Depending on the issue you're seeing, there may be a simple workaround.

Comment: Gonna agree on the "don't care" path. Website I made at work showed issues on the one guy's computer. Reason? Running FF 2.0.17 or something like that. Solution? Told him to upgrade, and it was all good. (We do testing on FF 3.x, IE7, IE8, and, when we still had it, IE6)

Comment: Why negative marking for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked stats on two sites I own. One has 40% overall Firefox share, the other one is more inline with global esitmates. On both sites, Firefox 2.x had less than **0.4%** share.

**Don't worry about it.**

Comment: Wanna link to the stats, so we can check them out? I'm kinda curious on what they show, aside from the 0.4%.

Comment: @Slokun: I don't have a link at the moment, I'm just reading from my Google Analytics. Maybe I'll put up a public page at some point - it'll certainly be better than everyone blindly quoting w3schools figures all the time.